# Can I account for both in and float types

Tags: python

So say I have some user input saved in a variable. Can I account for the user entering both an integer and a floating point number. for example

```
        gas = (input('How much gas did you have?'))
```

like above can whatever is in 'gas' be changed depending on another condition?
THANKS

Comment: Whatever you want to do, you can very likely do it. [ask]

Comment: Do you want to check if the user entered an integer or a float?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input()` returns a string, so you'll need to convert that to either an int or float. I'd recommend float since so you don't truncate the input to an int.

You could do something like

```py
gas = float(input('How much gas did you have?'))
```